# Trouble debugging a wrong data type error for a custom VBA function in excel 2010

Tags: excel, vba

I have been trying to learn more about excel (specifically how to utilize VBA well) and have been making a simple RPG in excel.

I tried to make a relatively simple function but I am running into an error that I can't seem to identify. The code itself doesn't seem to have any errors but my goal is to use the function in Excel's normal view and check if a string is equal to the strings in another sheet.

Basically, =CheckMonster(A1) or something like that. However, whenever I try to input it, I get a type error.

```
Function CheckMonster(mon As String)
Dim n As Integer

For n = 1 To 100
    If mon = Worksheets("monsterdatabase").Cells(1, n).Value Then
        ActiveSheet.Range("G2").Value = Worksheets("monsterdatabase").Cells(2, n).Value
        ActiveSheet.Range("G3").Value = Worksheets("monsterdatabase").Cells(3, n).Value
        ActiveSheet.Range("G4").Value = Worksheets("monsterdatabase").Cells(4, n).Value
        ActiveSheet.Range("G5").Value = Worksheets("monsterdatabase").Cells(5, n).Value
    Else: mon = ""
    End If
Next
End Function
```

Ideally, I would like it if I could make so that as soon as a change a given cell, the numbers would automatically update. However, I wasn't sure how to do this outside of brute forcing all the possible strings.

Comment: `mon as Range` if you want to provide a Range and not a literal string. If you want to provide a string you need to wrap it in double quotes like `=CheckMonster("A1")`...Also use `StrComp()` function to compare strings

Comment: A function returns a value to the cell in which it is located.  In general, you cannot use a function to write to other cells.  Your function seems to be wanting to modify cells G2:G5.  In addition, your function never returns any value at all.

Comment: +1 to Ron's comment. I have addressed this issue - plus optimised the code - below.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

- avoids a loop by finding your string (I used `strIn`) in a single shot looking *backwards* from the range of interest
- uses a `Sub` to update the cells not a `Function` (wont work as you have it)

*code*

```
Sub Test()
Dim strIn As String
strIn = "fred"
Call UpdateMe(strIn)
End Sub

Sub UpdateMe(ByVal strIn)
Dim rng1 As Range
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Sheets("monsterdatabase")
Set rng1 = ws.Range("A1:CV1").Find(strIn, ws.[a1], xlValues, xlWhole, xlByColumns, xlPrevious)
If Not rng1 Is Nothing Then
ActiveSheet.Range("G2:G5").Value = rng1.Offset(1, 0).Resize(4, 1).Value
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Ok so I think I understand how this code works but now I am confused how it would work. I guess I could put it in a button but would it be possible to make it run automatically?